# Duplicate records with Breezejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I'm having a problem counting records with breeze.
I want to count the number of customers. The first time the counter appears right (i.e. 300).
Also I have another menu option with activities and some activities can have related customers.

My problem is that when I take the records from local cache (executeLocally), is adding customers from Activities and I'm receiving 350 customers and not 300 as the good result.

Why Breezejs is adding customers from related entity to customers collection?

Comment: I believe that is because those extra 50 customers all have unique keys. Breeze will return all entities from local cache if you ask for it. On the other hand, if you're claiming that the '50' are duplicates of the original '300' and that they should not be returned, please post more details (code snippets, etc) to your post. In particular, some proof showing that a customer in the '50' group has the same key as a customer in the '300' group.

Comment: Hi Denis, you are right. The extra customers have unique keys. My problem is with the filter of data. Local data was not filtered. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's possible to add two groups of predicates? An example in normal text could be: (search for active records) and ((name contains xxxx) or (vat contains xxxx)). I've tried with two where clauses but it's not working.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You have to create 2 Breeze predicates, combine them and use it in the one where clause. See http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples#CompositeWhere for some examples.